# Usages of simple future and relative clauses

Tags: grammar

I am learning English and went across a question from a practice problem set, and I don't know the difference between these two.

Here are the three conditions that need to be met:

1. Have to use the words "lucky", "carry"
2. Have to use simple future like "will", "be going to"
3. Have to use relative clauses: "who", "which", "that"

Here are the two proposed usage:

1. If we are lucky, we will see octopuses that carry coconut shells.
2. If we are lucky, we will be able to see octopuses that are carrying coconut shells.

(The proposed answer is the second one, but I am not sure why. *I thought they are both correct.* )

Could someone explain to me why the second one is more correct?

Comment: It's impossible to say which is "more correct" without knowing more about the way the test is being judged. They are both grammatical. On the surface, it's entirely opinion-based.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that they are both grammatical. Could you explain the difference between "Will be able to see octopuses that carry shells" and "Will be able to see octopuses that are carrying shells"? Not sure what the difference is here.

Comment: Simply between those two, *that carry* means something that's habitual, while *are carrying* is something that's actually happening at the present time.